# Port not accessible outside local machine

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a server with port 3002 inside the linux subsystem.
However I am not able to access the server outside of my local machine of the same network.

#### Problem

How do I access a server running inside the Windows Linux Subsystem from other devices within the same network?

#### Assuming

- My machine local IP address is `192.168.1.10`
- My server is running at port `3002`

#### What is working:

1. Server hosted in linux subsystem is accessible by any browser on the **same machine** via `localhost:3002` and `192.168.1.10:3002`.
2. Server hosted in Windows (not inside linux subsystem) is accessible outside of the local machine via `192.168.1.10:3002`

#### What is not working:

1. Server hosted inside linux subsystem is not accessible by devices on the same network via `192.168.1.10:3002`

Comment: Check your firewall is allowing the requests.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the tip. I have checked my Windows Defender Firewall. It is indeed blocking the TCP connection. I was able to connect by turn off the firewall entirely. However, I cannot identify the correct app to "allow connection" in the firewall. Adding `Microsoft Bash Launcher` (bash.exe) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There's no pretty way to automatically allow all WSL programs through the Control Panel Firewall settings. To get it to work, you have to use Windows Firewall with Advanced Security to set a port exception, rather than a program exception.

1. search for "windows firewall with advanced security"
2. Add a new inbound rule, with a type of port
3. Allow the port (3002/TCP)